# asp.net core identity + api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just started learning asp.net core. I would like to create a simple web app, where I would have a rest API in asp.net core and then a separate frontend with some angular consuming that API.

I just got a bit stuck trying to figure out ASP.NET Core Identity and cookie/token authentication...

My question is pretty simple: Can I just create an API and use Entity Framework for database handling and ASP.NET Core Identity to handle creating and managing users and authorization? Do I have to also to use some JWT, OAuth or anything like that? It's just this is all super new to me and I am getting confused, because every example/tutorial shows it in a different way and I am getting very confused...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can create and consume without any identity and cookie/token authentication.

Comment: Right, but can I use identity (I want to have users that will be able to log in, I want to restrict access to the api based on users roles etc) so i want to use asp net core identity. Can i do it without any token authentication?

Comment: You can do this but need to handle and maintain session on your api. Browser did this for us but in api you need to handle this as well.

Comment: @Ahmar you should't maintain sessions for API, they relay o REST verbs and must be stateless as HTTP it self.You can add support to JWT based on this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/27/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: I think this will help you. http://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/11/30/asp-net-identity-core-from-scratch/

Comment: check this repo using asp.net core identity + openidconnect https://github.com/kkagill/ContosoUniversity-Backend

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a project that's very similar. Check out IdentityServer4 https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/index.html. It's an open source OpenID Connect/OAuth 2 framework for ASP.NET Core created by the guys from leastprivilege https://leastprivilege.com.

You can handle protecting your APIs with JWTs and configure IdentityServer to use ASP.NET Core Identity for its user store. This section here describes protecting the API:  https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/configuration/apis.html

This is basically how you add ASP.NET Identity, IdentityServer, and configure IdentityServer to use ASP.NET Identity in your Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddMvc();

// Adds IdentityServer
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
}
```

Then protecting an API is just a few lines of code in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io",
        AllowedScopes = { "api1" },
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Then you would have to configure your angular app to be a "client" of IdentityServer and be able to access your API "resource". There is a whole tutorial on adding JavaScript clients: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html

Answer (score 0):

> Can I just create an API and use Entity Framework for database
>   handling and ASP.NET Core Identity to handle creating and managing
>   users and authorization?:

ASP.NET Core Identity Framework utilizes Entity Framework to handle/manage user authentication and authorization. When implemented, the framework will generate the databases and tables it needs for Identity Framework using Entity Framework. So when writing your api/logic for user management using Identity Framework, you will have to use EF. For all other Models/Entities you can just use your own Database (which is separate from the Identity Databases) and still choose to use EF for that part but that's up to you.

> Do I have to also to use some JWT, OAuth or anything like that?

This is also up to you and is supported but not mandatory.